# Time calculation in bash

Tags: bash, time

We have a little issue with a time calculation in Bash.

Lets give you a little explaination about the situation up here.

We download every 5 minutes one file from an FTP server. This file contains time information about the data in this file. But the timeformat of the file is in UTC, and our local time is UTC+2. The files contains information about the past 5 minutes from local time. Now we have the following code:

```
TIMESTAMP=$(echo "$(TZ=UTC date "+%Y%m%d%H%M") - ($(date +%M)%5)-5" | bc)
```

That works well for several hours but after 55 minutes it becomes a problem. So we dont able to get the files with the 55 minutes, 60 minutes.

So if local time is: 19:47
The file with time 17:40 (utc) is available on the server at 19:45 local time

The time the files are available on the server are not constant too bad...
19:00, 19:05, 19:10 etc... but sometimes the file is one minute later....

This is my crontab file:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/kbroeren/cronscripts
*/1 * * * * /home/kbroeren/cronscripts/radar >> /home/kbroeren/radar_log.txt 2>&1
*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/bin/python /home/kbroeren/cronscripts/radar_plot.py >>/home/kbroeren/out.txt 2>&1
```

Is there a better and correct way to do this ?

Comment: I would not try to guess what the server's filename will be. I would look for the latest file on the server and see if you already have downloaded it. Also, you should expect that the clock on the local machine may not be in sync with the clock on the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `%s`:

```
date +%s
```

This returns:

```
   %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

You'd need to change the arithmetic a bit, though.

Comment: Thanks, but we dont use the seconds, THis is a sample filename from the data file: 201404041740.h5

Comment: @user3408380 What does _filename_ have to do with the date calculation?

Comment: We estimate the filename before to download the file, becaus there are about 200 files on the ftp server, we want to get the latest, right one.

Comment: @user3408380 You might want to edit your question instead to put in relevant information.

Comment: @user3408380 I think what devnull meant was that you could convert all dates to be in units of seconds, and then do the math on them, and then convert back if needed. And he doesn't mean seconds as in the last two digits of an "hh:mm:ss" time string, he means total number of seconds since January 1, 1970, which in Linux/Unix land, is referred to as the "Epoch", which is nothing more than an agreed-to base date and time upon which all other date/time computations are made.

Comment: @user3408380 Using your example of "201404041740" (and assuming this is in UTC, not UTC-2 or some other time zone), that date/time is equivalent to 1,396,633,200 seconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. Look at Emmet's answer to see how to convert to seconds. Once you convert everything to seconds, the math becomes easier and you'll no longer be limited to 55 minutes. Then convert back as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `date` command can convert to and from a number of date and time formats. If you want to do arithmetic with dates and times, it's probably easiest to convert to “seconds since the unix epoch”, do the arithmetic, and convert back to the time format of your choice.

You might consider something like:

```
date --date="@$(echo $(TZ=UTC date +%s) - $(date +%s)'%(5*60)-(5*60)' | bc)"
```